# Is this true that $\sum_{v=0}^k (-1)^v{a+v-1 \choose v}{b+k-v-1 \choose k-v}$ is the coefficient of $t^k$ in $(\frac{1}{1+t})^a(\frac{1}{1-t})^b$

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, binomial-coefficients, combinations

I was reading a paper, in which the author assumed that

$$\sum_{v=0}^k (-1)^v{a+v-1 \choose v}{b+k-v-1 \choose k-v}$$ is the coefficient of $$t^k $$ in $$\left(\frac{1}{1+t}\right)^a\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)^b $$ when |t|<1

I tried some examples and it seems to be true. But I wonder how can I prove (disprove) it?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem

Comment: Thank you! So it is correct right? This makes me comfortable and I can continue my reading.,.,

Answer (score 2):

Expanding using the binomial theorem and applying [upper negation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Negated_Upper_Index_of_Binomial_Coefficient) gives$$\begin{align}
A=\left(\frac 1{1+t}\right)^a=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\binom{-a}r t^r
=\sum_{r=0}^\infty \underbrace{(-1)^r\binom{a+r-1}{r}t^r}_{f(r)}\\
B=\left(\frac 1{1+t}\right)^b=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\binom{-b}r t^r=
\sum_{r=0}^\infty
\underbrace{(-1)^r\binom{b+r-1}{r}t^r}_{g(r)}\end{align}$$
Using the [Cauchy Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) we have
$$\begin{align}
A\cdot B=\left(\frac 1{1+t}\right)^a \left(\frac 1{1+t}\right)^b
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{v=0}^k \;f(v)\cdot g(k-v)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{v=0}^k (-1)^v\binom{a+v-1}vt^v\cdot (-1)^{k-v}\binom{b+k-v-1}{k-v}t^{k-v}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\color{red}{\underbrace{\sum_{v=0}^k (-1)^k\binom{a+v-1}v\binom{b+k-v-1}{k-v}}_\text{coefficient of $t^k$}}\;\; t^k
\end{align}$$